# How to update self-reference graph using GraphDiff?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, graphdiff

I am using **GraphDiff** to update entity framework graphs and when I am trying to update self-referenced graph like this way:

```
 dbContext.UpdateGraph(updatedStorageRequest, storageRequestMap => storageRequestMap
                    .OwnedCollection(oc => oc.PhysicalObjects, physicalObjectMap => physicalObjectMap
                           .OwnedCollection(oc => oc.SubPhysicalObjects))
                );
```

updatedStorageRequest is model which contains PhysicalObjects which are self-referenced data.

It will persist only the first PhysicalObject and it deletes all SubPhysicalObjects(the updatedStorageRequest it contains correct data with SubPhysicalObjects for each level in the hierarchy).

How can I update graph using GraphDiff when there is self-referenced model?

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with the fact that GraphDiff currently doesn't support mapping of recursive relationships of non-predetermined depth via the fluent API.